# <sj:select> not calling action

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, struts2

I feel this is a really easy fix but I'm stumped.  I've been searching around all day but my code seems to match that of working examples.
I'm using Struts+SpringMVC+Hibernate and I'm in the process of replacing all my dojo tags with jQuery tags.  The jQuery dropdown is not calling the associated action.

Here is the relevant code:

**Struts.xml**

```
<action name="getListOfCities" class="cityActions">
        <result type="json">
            <param name="root">cities</param>
        </result>
</action>
```

**Page.jsp**

```
<s:url id="cityList" action="getListOfCities"/>
     <sj:autocompleter name="cities" href="%{cityList}" list="cities" selectBox="true"/>
```

**CityAction.java**

```
public class CityActions implements ModelDriven<CityVO> {

CityService cityService;
private Map<String, String> cities = new HashMap<String, String>();
CityVO city = new CityVO();

public void setCityService(CityService cityService) {
    this.cityService = cityService;
}

public CityVO getModel(){
    return city;
}

public String execute() {
    return Action.SUCCESS;
}   

public String addCity(){
    try{
        cityService.addCity(city);
        return "SUCCESS";}
    catch(Exception e){
        return "ERROR";
    }catch(Throwable t){
        return "ERROR";
    }
}

public Map<String, String> getCities() {
    List<CityVO> cityList = cityService.listCities();

    Iterator<CityVO> iterator = cityList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        CityVO fac = iterator.next();
        cities.put(fac.getCityName(), Integer.toString(fac.getCityId()));
    }
    return cities;
}
```

The dropdown menu shows up but is unpopulated.  This is what I had before which worked fine:

```
<s:url id="cityList" action="getListOfCities" />
<sx:autocompleter href="%{cityList}" name="cities" keyValue="0" value="---- SELECT ONE-----"/>
```

Does anyone have a solution to this?  I've made sure to add

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
```

and inside head:

```
<sj:head jqueryui="true"/>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, i just read the api for both href, they have different meaning.check this out: sj(http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/AutocompleterTag), sx(http://struts.apache.org/2.0.12/docs/autocompleter.html). So i think you should populate your collection before it needs..

Comment: I don't understand, the example does it similar to me.  The issue isn't with the action not populating the dropdown; the issue is the action isn't being called at all.  I put system.out.println statements in all the methods in the action class and I am not seeing anything.

Comment: What version of S2? (I'm still baffled, are you seriously using two completely different MVC frameworks in the same project?) Anything in the JavaScript console? Server logs?

Comment: I'm using struts 2.3.3 and struts-jquery-plugin 3.3.1.  From what I understand using Spring and Struts is fairly common although I certainly don't know enough about them to comment on whether integrating them is a good idea.  I've come far enough into the project though that it is too late to remove either one.

I've installed firebug to help me fix this problem but it is not showing any JSON output from sj:select.  The console is also not picking up any of the System.out.println statements from the action class.

Comment: Using Spring and Struts, yes; using Spring MVC and Struts, no. I'd recommend creating a minimal failing example project (i.e., everything necessary to reproduce just the jquery failure, not your app's domain) and put it on github. Follow up with a comment (please use an @davenewton, otherwise I won't be notified) and I'll take a look; I can't reproduce the problem yet.

Comment: I was told this was using Spring MVC but you are probably right that is isn't specifically MVC.  I can see in my /lib I'm using struts2-spring-plugin-2.3.3.jar.  
I will do that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Too long for comment. Cobbled together a partial version of something similar to your snippets.)

The primary issue is that your result sets `root` to `cities`, meaning the returned JSON has no `cities` key, so the autocomplete's `list` attribute doesn't know where to get its data.

That said: there *is* something funky with the `selectBox` functionality in this version; when I remove that attribute I see data when I type, with it set to true, I get nothing.

I don't, however, see selection filtering, meaning that even though it's correctly highlighting matching characters, non-matching entries aren't being removed; I believe they should be.

Unrelated, but why bother creating a map from the VOs? Unless I had a decent reason (e.g., `CityVO` is too big or contains sensitive info) just use the `listKey` and `listValue` attributes and use what the service already returns.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.  You mentioned that the JSON won't have a proper key, but I'm not even getting to that point as my action isn't being called.  I'm working on creating a barebones version just to show the failure to upload to github.

I inherited this project with one partially working example (gets values from non-dependent drop-down, queries database, returns list of matches) and I've built off from there.  It used sx:select.  I've looked through the dojo docs and it works well with maps.  Maps are also convenient because we can use the public key as the map value.

Comment: Hmm.. It seems like the action is getting called now.  I can see the proper JSON being returned using firebug.  I will fix the primary issue you mentioned and let you know if I have any problems.  If not I'll accept the answer.

Comment: I've tried, as per your suggestion, just returning the list of VOs given by the service. In firebug I can see the JSON results are properly working, however the dropdown doesn't populate. Even if I remove selectBox it still is empty, and it is too small in width to type in.

New code:
<sj:select name="cityList2" href="%{cityList}" list="cityList2" listKey="cityList2.cityId" listValue = "cityyList2.cityName" delay="50"/>

Where cityList2 is the returned List<CityVO>, and cityName/cityId are variables with proper get/set methods in the VO.

Comment: Managed to track down the issue in firebug, will post a new problem.  Thanks for your help.