# sj:select in struts 2 can't parse JSON

Tags: jquery, json, struts2, firebug

I am building a page with struts + spring + hibernate.  I have a jQuery select widget that is supposed to load a list of values from the database, but it isn't populating.
This is a continuation of this thread: [<sj:select> not calling action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11334673/sjselect-not-calling-action) as I'm slowly narrowing done the cause of this problem.

Here is my code:

**struts.xml**

```
<action name="getListOfCities" class="cityActions">
    <result type="json" name="SUCCESS">
        <param name="root">cities</param>
    </result>
</action>
```

**page.jsp**

(For Map)

```
<s:url id="cityList" action="getListOfCities"/>
  <sj:select name="select" href="%{cityList}" list="cities" headerKey="-1" emptyOption="true" headerValue="Pick one"/>
```

**CityAction.java**

```
public class CityActions extends ActionSupport implements ModelDriven<CityVO> {

public void setCityService(CityService cityService) {
    this.cityService = cityService;
}

public CityVO getModel(){
    System.out.println("Executing getModel()");
    return city;
}

public String execute() {
    System.out.println("Executing cities");
    return "SUCCESS";
}   

public String getJSON(){
    return execute();
}
public String addCity(){
    try{
        cityService.addCity(city);
        return "SUCCESS";}
    catch(Exception e){
        return "ERROR";
    }catch(Throwable t){
        return "ERROR";
    }
}
public Map<String, String> getCities() {
    List<CityVO> cityList = cityService.listCities();

    Iterator<CityVO> iterator = cityList.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        CityVO fac = iterator.next();
        cities.put(fac.getCityName(), Integer.toString(fac.getCityId()));
    }
    System.out.println("Cities: " + cities);

    return cities;
}   

public List<CityVO> getCityList2(){
    System.out.println("Getting list of cityVOs");
    cityList2 = cityService.listCities();
    return cityList2;
}

}
```

My action class supports either returning the JSON object as a VO or as a Map.  The current page.jsp code is for the map feature.

I'm using firebug to try and figure out the problem.  I can see my JSON object being returned properly.  It looks like:

```
{"Foo":"3","Bar":"4","Hello":"2"}
```

I'm getting an error though and I know it is from the sj:select widget; If I remove it, the error goes away.

```
a is undefined
f()jquery....min.js (line 2)
a = undefined
c = function()
d = undefined
```

Google has led me to believe that this indicates an issue with parsing the JSON value, but I couldn't find any examples relating to the struts2-jquery plugin.  I've tried adding dataType="json" to my sj:select but that does not resolve the issue.

If anyone has suggestions, that would be much appreciated.  I've been stuck on this for quite a few days now.

Comment: Have you tried just using jQuery directly?

Comment: With the standard s:select?  I was told that I should just use the struts2-jquery plugin as it leaves less room for error.

Comment: We went over this--your select tag is trying to find a json value named "cities", do you see such a value in your json? I don't.

Comment: No I don't.  I'm not sure what to put, since I'm using the same syntax as the ones in the plugin showcase.  I've tried to remove the <param name="root"> but that stops the proper json object from being returned.  What should it be instead?  I don't think I'm quite getting it.

Comment: How does that stop the proper json object from being returned? Also, if you don't use a "@" I won't be notified you responded to my comment, i.e., @user1287523.

Comment: @DaveNewton this is what is returned if I delete the param line:
{"code":null,"temperature":null,"foo":null,"bar":null} etc.  It prints out all the variables in the VO and returns the strings as null and the ints as 0.

Comment: Then you're returning the wrong value, obviously--you're the one trying to get a list of cities out of an action defined as ModelDriven<CityVO>, not sure what you expect. Can't have it both ways (well, you can, although I'm not sure I *would*).

Comment: @DaveNewton what value am I returning then?  Is it calling the getModel() function?

Comment: Yes, you defined the action as ModelDriven--might want to spend some time figuring out S2 before going too much further; it'll save you some time in the long run.

Comment: @DaveNewton Okay, thanks.  If I create a separate action that doesn't implement ModelDriven for the purpose of returning a list of VOs to the jQuery object, would that work?

Comment: If you do it right, probably.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thanks for your help.  I'll try not to bug you for a while haha.  I can see now why this project is using ModelDriven: the person I've inherited it from was coming from Struts 1.

Comment: It's not an issue with ModelDriven per se, it's just that you're trying to work around it inappropriately, while trying to present data to a component that expects it in a certain way.

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this action:

```
<action name="getListOfCities" class="cityActions">
    <result type="json"/>
</action>
```